# creating UITableViews in array block enumeration causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, objective-c-blocks, retain

so the story goes like this :)

i am trying to block enumerate objects in an NSArray and dynamically create UITableViews for each of them and add them in UIScrollView. i am using [Lighter View Controllers from www.objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/lighter-view-controllers/) for the sake of readability and reusability. the dataSource gets created for each UITableView separately. the problem is i crash all the time with

```
-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
```

i found out from posts on stack that objects in block enumeration are weak retained for speed concerns and can confirm that the dataSource gets actually deallocated for each table.

i even tried to init ArrayDataSource with __strong but with no effect.

```
__strong ArrayDataSource *customdayTableDataSource = [[ArrayDataSource alloc] initWithConfigureCellBlock:configureCell cellIdentifier:DayTableCellIdentifier];
```

what am i doing wrong in the block? can you please point me the right direction?

```
TableViewCellConfigureBlock configureCell = ^(id cell, id object) {
    [cell configureForObject:object];
};

[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    int tableHorizontalPosition = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * idx;               
    int tableHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height; 

    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableHorizontalPosition, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, tableHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [table setDelegate:self];

    ArrayDataSource *customDataSource = [[ArrayDataSource alloc] initWithConfigureCellBlock:configureCell cellIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

    [customTableDataSource setOriginalData:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil]];

    [table setDataSource:customTableDataSource];

    [[self myUIScrollView] addSubview:table];

}];
```

as pointed out with [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) i added each dataSource to an NSArray initialized out of the scope of the block. this solved my problem. thank you

Comment: The problem is not that objects in the block enumeration are weak. It's that the table view's `dataSource` property is weak and your `ArrayDataSource` instances don't live beyond the end of the block.

Comment: but as i said i tried to init it with __strong with no help. and should not the retain count go up by one when i assaign it to the table?

Comment: Adding `__strong` doesn't do anything there, it's already the default.  You need something with a longer scope to hold a reference to it.  The table holds a weak reference to it's datasource so the retain count wouldn't go up when you assign it.

Comment: It's already strong, that's the default for a variable. And no, the table doesn't retain it. That's what I said in my first comment. The `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of `UITableView` are `weak`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people said in comments, you must create your datasorces somewhere where they will be "alive" as long as the tableviews, or maybe easier solution would be to create strong reference using objc_setAssociatedObject

In your class declare some `static char strongReferenceKey`

and in your block, after setting datasource, do:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(table, &strongReferenceKey, customDataSource, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

That way table will have strong reference on the datasource, which will be released when table gets deallocated.

P.S. Make sure you import runtime.h:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```